# Wildfly admin: Use encrypted password in mail subsystem

Tags: email, encryption, wildfly-10

I am using a JBoss Wildfly 10.1 to deploy several war files. My goal is to define a mail session in the mail subsystem. I was able to achieve this, but I have learned, that the password is stored in the standalone.xml in clear text. Now I am willing to use an encrpyted password.

While defining the data resource, I used a security domain, to achieve this goal. But in the admin tool, when regarding the mail subsystem I can't figure out, how to make use of a security domain, since there's no input field for that, only user name and password.

So, my question is: Is it possible to use an encrypted password in the wildfly mail subsystem and, if yes, how?